# Suggest/Recommend/Search Google Doodle featuring topics

Tags: google-search, google-feedback, google-doodle

**How and where do we suggest or recommend Google Doodle featuring topics?**

For example, today is June 13, which is the birthday of one of the greatest physicists, James Clerk Maxwell. As far as I understand, there has been no  Google Doodle dedicating to him so far, for all these years.

Are there are also Google Doodle dedicating to the following scientists and/or mathematicians?

- Thomas Young (June 13, 1773 - May 10, 1829)

  ["The Last Man Who Knew Everything"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Young_(scientist))
- James Clerk Maxwell (June 13, 1831 - November 5, 1879).

  ["second great unification in physics"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Clerk_Maxwell)
- Luis Walter Alvarez (June 13, 1911 - September 1, 1988).

  ["one of the most brilliant and productive experimental physicists of the twentieth century." --  Nobel Prize in Physics in 1968](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luis_Walter_Alvarez)
- John Forbes Nash (June 13, 1928 - May 23, 2015).

  [the only person to be awarded both the Nobel Memorial Prize in Economic Sciences and the Abel Prize -- Nobel Memorial Prize in Economic Sciences 1994](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Forbes_Nash_Jr.)
- Grigori Perelman (June 13, 1966 - ).

  [proved Thurston's geometrization conjecture and the Poincaré conjecture - Fields Medal 2006 and first Clay Millennium Prize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grigori_Perelman)

See: https://www.huffpost.com/entry/john-nash-james-clerk-maxwell-birthday_n_1594315

Answer (score 2):

> #### How can Google users/the public submit ideas for doodles?
>
> The doodle
> team is always excited to hear ideas from users – they can email
> **proposals@google.com** with ideas for the next Google doodle. The team
> receives hundreds of requests every day, so we, unfortunately, can't
> respond to everyone. But rest assured that we're reading them :)
>
> **https://www.google.com/doodles/about**

---

Google Doodles can be searched here: **https://www.google.com/doodles#archive**

Comment: @wonderich https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers